# How to implement a structured message for subscribing queue sent from python requests?

Tags: message-queue, publish-subscribe

For development purpose I am using ntfy.sh for publish and subscribe messages, since this queue system is not part of my main project, I not currently focusing on implementation of a queue but just use ntfy.sh queue subscription using json to send and receive the message on subscriber end.

I am sending the message using `request.post` in python.

```
 data = { "message": f"{message} {file_path}" }
    PUBLISH_URL = PUB_URL + "/" + PUB_TOPIC
    response = requests.post(
        PUBLISH_URL,
        data=json.dumps(data), 
        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    )
```

but the message received on the subscriber end is

```
{"id":"k2WktUGdGXom","time":1699727957,"expires":1699771157,"event":"message","topic":"demo_testing","message":"{\"message\": \"File modified /etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini\"}"}

{"id":"fKcm4eHvVWCY","time":1699727963,"expires":1699771163,"event":"message","topic":"demo_testing","message":"{\"message\": \"Not a git repository. /etc/php/8.1/apache2\"}"}
```